# Django forms {% ssi %} dont play nicely

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form that works perfectly when it is in its own template, however when I try to include it in another template using:

```
{% ssi '/home/.../templates/basic_draft_pick.html' parsed %}
```

It only renders the "submit" button.  The only thing the "parent" template has in it are the requisite `<HTML>`, `<head>`, `<body>` type tags.

I tried the same parent template with with another {% ssi %} template that uses a forloop, and the text around the forloop renders, but the loop itself doesn't render.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

EDIT:

draft_page.html:

```
<div id="basic_draft_form">

        <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Draft" />
        </form>

</div>
```

The Parent:

basic_draft_pick.html

```
{% load ssi from future %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Draft Page Template</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% ssi '/home/.../templates/basic_draft_pick.html' parsed %}

        <br />
        <br />              
    </body>

</html>
```

Please note that the elipse in the path above is the actual path and I can tell that the page is picked up because the button is rendered correctly.

Thank you,

dp

Comment: Did you specified `ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS` in your settings file?

Comment: I did.  at first it was giving me a "no allowed" error,  but once I included the ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS, that was cleared up.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you also add `{% load ssi from future %}` in the same template? Quoted paths are not supported by the default `ssi` in Django <1.5. So you need to load the future tag to utilize it that way. Also, it would be helpful to see the contents of basic_draft_pick.html.

Comment: I included the code above...Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but if you can't get the `ssi` tag to work with the `parsed` option, you might be able to use the `include` template tag instead.

Comment: I just updated to use include.  I get the same result...

Comment: Also, interestingly...the CSRF token doesn't work with either ssi or include.  it works perfectly in a template of it's own...

Comment: Actually, I started out with INCLUDE, I changed to SSI when INCLUDE didn't work as I expected.

Comment: You don't need `ssi` in this case, it's a classic case for `include`.

If switching to `include` doesn't help, I think the problem is in the view.